How to monitor Kafka DLQ with datadog?
I have a java spring boot app with kafka and want to monitor my DLQs with datadog. I need some kind of alerting (email) when a new message enters the DLQ topic. Using datadog as monitoring agent. I have found this guide from datadog but there is no specific part about alerting on a topic.
I have the metrics of kafka send to datadog, but don't know how I can monitor a topic, and set up alerting after that.
I try for example avg:kafka.net.bytes_out.rate{topic:kafkatest}
but the {topic:kafkatest} doesn't seem to work

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

You should be able to monitor bytes-in rate to any topic from the broker JMX

My question is how? I see a bunch of kafka monitors, but I don't see any that is usable on a specific topic. The bytes-in rate monitor I see is just for whole of Kafka, not a specific topic.

I'm not sure how your monitor is setup, but bytes in, out, and message-in rate do include a topic https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/kafka/monitoring.html#messagesinpersec

I used this tool to monitor kafka.
in the topic level dashboard, it shows the offset for each topic:
https://zoomphant.github.io/docs/manual/99_plugins/kafka/#topic-dashboard
use the left top to create alarm to send alert to email/slack etc.

